# Animation in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I got a listview with images and some info overlaying them. I want to make so, that when I tap an image info fades out from ALL OF THE LISTVIEW. then I can scroll images and tap on them for this info. how is it possible to do so?

Comment: By ALL OF THE LISTVIEW you mean all cells of list view? Do you have some source code to share?

Comment: yes, I mean that. nope, suppose I better dont share this hell...

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement an `onClickListener` for the image view. When you tap on an image the listener will be called and you can change the view state of the info.

Comment: sorry for saying that, but... captain, is it you??? (I know what to do with onClickListener. the biggest problem is animations)